# Use Visual Studio regex searching to find empty Try/Catch blocks

Tags: regex, vb.net, visual-studio

I've found a relevant C# version of this question, but I've failed to convert that to search for VB.net's syntax, and regexes aren't my strong suit in the first place, so I'll post what I've got and then throw myself upon the mercy of the stack.

I've managed to put together the regex:

```
Catch+\s+\b(_\w+|[\w-[0-9_]]\w*)\b+\s+As+\s+Exception+[\S|\r?\n]
```

which matches against `Catches` of unspecified exceptions (plus a linebreak, because that's part of what I'm working towards). I'm looking to extend that to look for empty Try/Catches, but apparently I'm missing something.

I'm adding `*+(Catch|End|Finally)` to the previous regex to give:

```
Catch+\s+\b(_\w+|[\w-[0-9_]]\w*)\b+\s+As+\s+Exception+[\S|\r?\n]*+(Catch|End|Finally)
```

which, as far as I can tell, should be matching against any mount of whitespace/linebreaks, and then a valid end-of-Catch keyword, but I stop getting results at that point.

What am I screwing up, here?

Comment: Might be worth capturing comments as well!

Comment: There are several things that are totally wrong in this regex. **1)** You're for example mixing character classes `[]` with grouping parenthesis `()`. **2)** `\b+` doesn't make sense at all and should throw an error **3)** Let's take `[\w-[0-9_]]`, `\w` means match digits, letters and underscore, now taking the whole character class into account, `[\w-[0-9_]]` means match digits, letters, underscore, hyphen, brackets `[]` and 0 to 9 again. **4)** `Catch+` what did I just read here ? match `Catc` and 1 or more `h`. Basically it's a mess and I would recommend you to learn regular expressions.

Comment: Learn [regex the hardway](http://regex.learncodethehardway.org/book/), [the standardway](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html) or just read the manual of your favorite language, most of the times it includes a section that covers regex. Some tools that may come handy : [auto-explainer](http://rick.measham.id.au/paste/explain.pl), [online tester](http://regex101.com) or visit the [regex chatroom](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25767/regex) for other 1337 tools and tricks :)

Comment: @HamZa microsofts find and replace tool has a real bastard version of regex. Same-but-different with only partial support.

Comment: @Gusdor yeah, but my point is that this regex doesn't make sense at all and that the OP should take a step back and learn the basics.

Comment: @HamZa The basics are relatively easy, because when you screw up, it crashes and gives you an error message you can work around and learn from. With Visual Studio's nearly-undocumented find and replace custom regex horror show, it just fails silently and makes you turn to StackOverflow for help.

Comment: @Frosty840 "custom regex horrorshow". Coming to theatre near you, this halloween. *shudder*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
(Catch(\s?.+As.+)?(\r?\n|\s)*)+(Finally)?(\r?\n|\s)*End Try
```

Took me ages to work out. Visual studio is a real pain sometimes :D The secret is correct matching of line breaks. I repeat `(\r?\n|\s)*` quite a lot. This matches `\r\n` or `\n` or `\s` zero or many times.

**What were you screwing up?**

Often in regex and programming in general, simplicity is key. You were trying to match the full VB.net exception handling syntax and making a tiny mistake somewhere. Sometimes, matching every character (.*) will do if you really don't care about the content (you want to skip areas, like here we dont care about the actual exception type, if it is even there!).I'm pretty sure visual studio uses lazy iteration as standard.

Comment: Hrm. It's matching catch blocks, but it's not excluding the ones containing code, sadly. The search results it's returning are really weird, too, but I expect that's more to do with Visual Studio than anything else...

Comment: @Frosty840 was it matching the End Try line only if code existed? I've fixed that now.